# Malloc/Bus error with fprintf

Tags: c++, printf

I am getting a malloc error with bus error on using the fprintf statements in C++ (code below). Any pointers on what could be going wrong? Note absAmb and dModel both have valid values. Thanks.

```
FILE *fPtr;
char fName[100];

sprintf(fName, "Info.dat", block);
if ( (fPtr = fopen(fName,"w")) == NULL )
{  
    return( FALSE );
}

int absAmb = rint(fda[0]/prf[0]);

fprintf(fPtr, "  %d", absAmb); //ERROR LINE
fprintf(fPtr, "  %d", dModel);
fclose(fPtr);
```

Comment: what is `block` in `sprintf`?

Comment: What is f in your fprintf(f)? Do you meant fPtr?

Answer (score 2):

```
fprintf(f, "  %d", absAmb); //ERROR LINE
```

You use wrong variable in `fprintf`

```
fprintf(fPtr, "  %d", absAmb); // <--- fPtr
```

Answer (score 1):

What is 'f'?  You stored the results of fopen into fPtr but then do a fprintf to f.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your file pointer variable "fPtr", but you are trying to write to "f".  Change your fprintf() call to use fPtr as the first parameter.